# Selecting text within div

Tags: jquery

I have a div element with some text in it. I need to be able to select:
1. div itself, and
2. only text within that div

```
<div class="myDiv">some text</div>
```

So I am able to select div, by class name

```
$(".myDiv").hover(...);
```

But I'm having difficulty with the text. Tried the following

```
$(".myDiv").contents().eq(0).text().hover(...);
```

but no luck. Also, when I hover over text I need to select that text only, and not the parent div.

[image]

Comment: and what about simple `$(".bHdr").text()` ?

Comment: What do you mean "select"? selecting an element using jquery is not the same as selecting text using the mouse. Also, are you trying to attach a hover event handler to the actual text?

Comment: @Sergio I do something else on hover, after I select.

Comment: @santa what do you mean by select? with mouse? or add color to text?

Comment: @santa Looks like you want a border on the text when hover, is that it?

Comment: @Sergio Yes, among other things. I can get that, I'm just having difficulty selecting that test.

Comment: Don't take me wrong but I still dont understand what you mean with select.

Comment: No problem.  Let's say I need to draw an outline around those two elements. I can now do it around the div, but not around the text. I use  $(".myDiv").hover(function () { $(this).css("outline", "1px solid red"); } );

Comment: I would do that in css, not js using the :hover rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/et2tz/)**

Try this

I guess this is what you need

```
(function findTextNodes(current, callback) {
    for(var i = current.childNodes.length; i--;){
        var child = current.childNodes[i];
        if(3 === child.nodeType)
            callback(child);
        findTextNodes(child, callback);
    }
})(document.getElementById('myDiv'), function(textNode){ 
    $(textNode).replaceWith('<span class="textNode">' + textNode.nodeValue + '</span>');
});

$('.textNode').hover(function(){

    $(this).css('color', 'white'); 
},function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not realize that I can not select the div like this... It just gets me text. I need to be able to select text only when the move over the text. If it's over the div, it should select div. How do I combine the two?

Comment: Wow! Thanks. What's if(3 === child.nodeType) ?

Comment: means 3 is the nodeType for textnode, its checking whether nodeType is 3  check this out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

Answer (score 3):

All you should need is the following:

```
var txt = $('.myDiv').text();
```

Comment: I tied that too. When I hover over text I need to select that text only, and not the parent div.

Comment: @santa - I don't understand what you mean by "select" I guess.  The code above gets the text within the div, not the div itself

Answer (score 0):

```
var html= $('.myDiv').html(); // Select div itself
var text= $('.myDiv').text(); // To get only the text
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to add text try:

`$(".myDiv").contents().eq(0).innerHTML('YOUR TEXT HERE').hover(...);`

Comment: Both `innerHTML` and `.html` are same!!

Comment: Although I'm not sure what this section is for: `.contents().eq(0)` Plain and simple adding HTML / text inside a div you can use: `$(".bHdr").innerHTML('YOUR TEXT');` :D

Comment: @user1671639 Modified the answer instead, .html will replace the Div with your html and the innerHTML is 'less frowned apon' XD

Comment: It has to be dynamic, i.e. I don't know what the string of text is.

Comment: @santa Are you using PHP also? If yes, you can convert PHP variables to  javascript! :D

Comment: @santa Although `innerHTML` will allow you to add formatted text as well as plain text :)

Comment: @santa What's your hover code? This may make more sense if you were to explain some of the HTML also?